# Subscript out of bounds error with custom function in lidR::catalog_apply()

Tags: r, lidr

I am attempting to create a raster of pixel metrics for a large collection of lidar data using the `lidR::` package.  I want to first remove any outlier points in the point cloud, normalize the point cloud to a digital terrain model, and finally, calculate the standard z pixel metrics on a 20 m X 20 m grid.  I followed the guidance on the `lidR::` package's book and its vignettes for using the `catalog_apply()` engine.  I have created a "low level API" function that first has a conditional to check if the input is a `LAScatalog`, and then runs the function through `catalog_apply` , then checks if the input is a `LAScluster`, and then runs the function directly and clips the chunk buffers from the output, and then finally checks if the input is a `LAS`, and then explicitly runs the function.  I am struggling with getting the function to run properly on a `LAScatalog`.  When I run the function on a `LAS` file, it works with out error, however, when I run it on a `LAScatalog`, all chunks show an error on the plot, and when the routine finishes, it throws this error:

```
Error in any_list[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

This error makes me think that I am missing some sort of catalog_apply engine or SpatRaster driver option that tells the function how to merge the output chunks back together to form the final output, but I am not sure which option that would be, and I haven't been able to find any answers on the `lidR::` wiki page, vignettes, or book, nor can I find a similar issue here on Stackoverflow.  Any advice would be much appreciated. Below is my reproducible example:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(lidR)
library(future)

#Reading in the data##
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfile) # As LAScatalog
las<-readLAS(LASfile) # As LAS

####Custom function####
raster_metrics<-function(las, dtm_ras,  grid_size, sensitivity){#start function
  if(is(las, "LAScatalog")){#Start first conditional for LASCatalog
    options <-list(automerge=TRUE, need_buffer=TRUE)
    output<-catalog_apply(las, raster_metrics,  grid_size=grid_size, sensitivity=sensitivity, .options=options)
    return(output)
  } else { #end first condition start first else
    if (is(las, "LAScluster")){  #start second conditional for LAScluster
      las<-readLAS(las)
      if (is.empty(las)){return(NULL)}#Conditional for empty chunk (self contained)
      output_tmp<-raster_metrics(las, dtm_ras,  grid_size, sensitivity)
      bbox<-sf::st_bbox(las)
      output<-st_crop(output_tmp, bbox)
      return(output)
    } else {# End second conditional begin second else
      if (is(las, "LAS")){
        p95 <- pixel_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.95), grid_size)
        las <- merge_spatial(las, p95, "p95")
        las <- filter_poi(las, Z < p95*sensitivity)
        las$p95 <- NULL
        norm<-las - dtm_ras
        output<-pixel_metrics(norm, .stdmetrics_z, grid_size)
        return(output)
      }else { #end final conditional begin final else
        stop("This type is not supported.")
      }#end final else
    } #end second else
  } #end first else
}  #end function

##Creating a rasterized dtm to feed to the function##
dtm_ras<-rasterize_terrain(ctg, algorithm = knnidw())

##Defining some function and engine option setttings##
grid_size<-20.0
sensitivity<-1.2
chunk_size<-grid_size*50
chunk_buffer<-grid_size*2

##Setting driver and engine option parameters##
opt_output_files(ctg)<-paste0(tempdir(), "/{XCENTER}_{YCENTER}_{ID}_Norm_Height")
opt_chunk_size(ctg)<-chunk_size
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg)<-chunk_buffer
opt_wall_to_wall(ctg)<-TRUE
opt_stop_early(ctg)<-FALSE
opt_filter(ctg)<-"-drop_withheld"
opt_select(ctg)<-"xyz"
ctg@output_options$drivers$SpatRaster$param$overwrite<-TRUE

##Setting up parallel processing##
plan(multisession, workers = nbrOfWorkers()-1)
set_lidr_threads(nbrOfWorkers()-1)

##Running the function##
example1<-raster_metrics(las=ctg, dtm_ras = dtm_ras, grid_size = grid_size, sensitivity = sensitivity)#Throws error
example2<-raster_metrics(las=las, dtm_ras = dtm_ras, grid_size = grid_size, sensitivity = sensitivity)#Works without error
```

**UPDATE 2/3/2023**

Doing a little digging on my own, it appears that this error gets thrown by the internal `lidR:::` function `engine_merge()`, which has an argument `any_list=`.  This makes me think that somehow my function violates one of the template rules of `catalog_apply()`, but I copied the template verbatim from the vignette.  Hoping this elucidates the source of my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You missed to propagate `dtm_ras`

```r
output<-catalog_apply(las, raster_metrics,  dtm_ras = dtm_ras, grid_size=grid_size, sensitivity=sensitivity, .options=options)
```

2. You used incorrect package to crop

```r
bbox <-terra::ext(las)
output<-terra::crop(output_tmp, bbox)
```

With the following function it works in `sequential` mode

```r
raster_metrics<-function(las, dtm_ras,  grid_size, sensitivity)
{
  if(is(las, "LAScatalog")) 
  {
    options <-list(automerge=FALSE, need_buffer=TRUE)
    output<-catalog_apply(las, raster_metrics,  dtm_ras = dtm_ras, grid_size=grid_size, sensitivity=sensitivity, .options=options)
    return(output)
  } 
  else if (is(las, "LAScluster"))
  {
    las<-readLAS(las)
    if (is.empty(las)){return(NULL)}
    output_tmp <- raster_metrics(las, dtm_ras,  grid_size, sensitivity)
    bbox <-terra::ext(las)
    output<-terra::crop(output_tmp, bbox)
    return(output)
  } 
  else if (is(las, "LAS"))
  {
    p95 <- pixel_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.95), grid_size)
    las <- merge_spatial(las, p95, "p95")
    las <- filter_poi(las, Z < p95*sensitivity)
    las$p95 <- NULL
    norm <- las - dtm_ras
    output<-pixel_metrics(norm, .stdmetrics_z, grid_size)
    return(output)
  }
  else 
  {
    stop("This type is not supported.")
  }
}
```

However it does not work in parallel because `terra`'s `SpatRaster` are not serializable. To say it simple, when the `dtm_ras` is sent to each worker, it no longer exists. This is not an issue with `lidR` it is an issue with `terra`. In `lidR` functions, I use an internal workarounds to deal with `SpatRaster` by converting them to `raster`.

On your side the simplest option is to use a `RasterLayer` from `raster`.

Comment: Thanks so much Jean...and major kudos on the `lidR` package!   I appreciate the note about `SpatRaster` format not being serializable.  I will try to convert to raster formats.  I had been a little lazy and taken advantage of `terra::vrt()` to use a vrt of all of my dtms, but I think I can just use gdal to build a vrt and still call that in using `raster::`.  SO won't let me award the bounty for another few hours, but I will be sure to award it tomorrow.